# Ignet query on local node pontential issue?

Tags: ignite

New to ignite, i have a use case, i need to run a job to clean up. I have ignite embedded in our spring boot application, for multiple instances, i am thinking have the job run on each instance, then just query the local data and clean up those. Do you see any issue with this? I am not sure how often ignite does reshuffing data?

Thanks
Shannon

Comment: Could you give more details on what kind of jobs you run, how you use the data and what guarantees you need. It's not enough information in your question to give any definitive answer.

Comment: So it is a kafka streams app, for certain messages (A) i save to ignite and donot forward to the output topic, for messages B if there is a matching A, i combine them (copy some data from A to B), the combined message is forward to the output topic, A then is removed from ignite and sent to another topic. Thus there are some messages (A) in the ignite that are not matched/removed, i need a clean up job to check those in ignire (after certain time) and process them. I dont need any order guarantee or anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely do that.

With regards to data reshuffling, it will only happen when node is added or removed to cluster. However, `ignite.compute().affinityRun()` family of calls guarantees that code is ran near the data.

Otherwise, you could do `ignite.compute().broadcast()` and only iterate on each affected cache's local entries. You don't have the aforementioned guarantee then, though.